# How to just get selected value from iQuery Datepicker, but not allow it to set elements value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using this jQuery Datepicker: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
var options = {};
options.dateFormat = 'mm/dd/yy';
options.minDate = new Date();
options.maxDate = new Date('01/01/2020');

$("#datepicker").datepicker(options);
```

This method it populating HTML's element by it self. But I need just to get selected by user string value and I will do the rest by my self.

I saw there is .datepicker('getDate') method, but it looks like it still populates the element and returns date...
And how I can combine options with it..?

Comment: $("#datepicker") is input field?

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedDate = $('#datepicker').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#datepicker").on('input change', function() {
  var date = $(this).val();
  //clear input
  $(this).val("");
  //or customize as you like
  $(this).val(date.split(" ")[0]);
});
```